# Center UIImage Horizontally Constraint in UIView Not Working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, constraints

So I have been using the new Xcode 6.2 Auto Layout Preview and other features to get my app ready for all screen sizes. I am trying to constrain a UIImage to look  equally the same in every screen type. I have set up the constraints, and I am looking for it look the same, although it is not. Below are the screenshots of the constraints, storyboard view, and then the final compiled product. As you can see the image is not centered.

Constraints:

[image]

[image]

Here is the compiled version, obviously off.

[image: Here is the compiled version, obviously off.]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is : Center UIImageView Horizontally Constraint in UIViewController Not Working??

Comment: Try adding  leading space and trailing space constraints too!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to meet all your constraints and have a very large width for the imageView.  It has to align to a specific top and bottom edge, and then resize to width to meet the aspect ratio constraint.  It seems like the width it determines is larger than the width of the screen.  Basically, your image is in landscape, while the device is in portrait.

You could remove the bottom constraint, and add a constraint for the left and right edge.  This would make the imageView a specific width and a flexible height.